# retrieve font name from a font file in c#

Tags: c#, fonts

I'm developing a program in c# that shows fonts in a special directory and allows users to select and install fonts. Is there a method that can retrieve the font name from a font file? for example fontname is "New Font" but the font file name is "NewFontv2.ttf".

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in C#. Look inside the file if there is any line that contains something like "Font name" or something like that and extract the file name.

Or try using **GlyphTypeface Class**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.aspx

Hope it helps.